# How many times can I ask the same question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've asked the same question 3 times now.

The question is worded differently each time as I learn how to ask better questions that are more to the point.

I have seriously tried to find the solution on my own. I have not just asked without doing any personal effort, but the answers I get are the things that lead me to asking the question in the first place.

So I guess this is a two part question.

1. How can I get answers that are not "do the action that made you ask this question"?
2. How many times can I re-word my question before it starts getting closed as duplicates of my original unanswered question?

EDIT: The question on trial is how can I be a better programmer. Yes, is a bit vague which is why I reasked with more defined goals, but the only answer I get is: *practice*. While I accept that is necessary it is not helpful, recommended books, projects that would require particular advance skills/techniques, blogs to follow, anything like that would be good, but no one seems interested in writing an answer that is not "just write more code and see what happens". For a self-taught programmer that is no use for seeing if I am doing things properly, reinventing the wheel (I once tried to build my own vector class before I was told about them) or just badly hacking thing together.

EDIT 2: these are the three questions.

[Enhancing the level of my C/C++ code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/76081/22193)

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/82753/22193

[Professionalise this code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6294340/686054)

Comment: Please add links to your question(s). In general, you should edit your question instead of posting new ones, but it's hard to say more without looking at examples.

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/94484/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Comment: I suspect the problem is with how you ask the question.

If you can provide examples, we can critique them, and perhaps help you understand what you need to change to get the answers you want.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is an edit link under your question. You should click that link and edit your question instead of asking a new question.

[image]

Comment: Indeed. Editing your question to add things you've tried (especially those suggested in answers) is considered a Good Thing™.

Comment: Was about to write "Excellent mspaint skills" but then realised this is a programming forum and couldn't make that assumption!

Comment: @George: Actually, they are ["StackExchange™ SuperCollider Freehand Circle™ Editor"](http://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange-supercollider-freehand-circle-editor-now-supported-on-every-st) - skills ;-)

Comment: ok, now i have to move away from IE and use something that can use all these SE scripts i keep getting linked to!

Comment: @George I heartily endorse Chrome (google it) to the end.

Answer (score 18):

Your three examples are:

> What advice would you give to grow and enhance my knowledge and skills, specific resources would be greatly appreciated.

...

> How would you begin to bridge the gap from beginner to intermidate C++ programmer?

...

> This is code I wrote to for an rpg game to pick a target to attack. using it as an example could you show me better/more advanced/professional ways of doing it.

The problem is that these questions do not belong on any of the sites.  They aren't programming problems, they are programmer problems.  But the problem isn't objective - it's very subjective.  There's no "right" answer to your questions, just a lot of opinions and options you could try.

Asking this question over and over again won't give you the right answer.  Others have tried to answer your question, and as [Kate points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94484/how-many-times-can-i-ask-the-same-question/94491#94491) the only real way to improve your programming is by practicing.  I'd add observing and helping to that as well - the more questions you answer, the more help you give others, and the more you read other people's code and answers to problems, the more you will learn about programming, and what makes a good programmer.

You can't expect to read a few paragraphs of an answer and suddenly upgrade your skills from beginner to intermediate, or intermediate to advanced, or to expert, etc.  Further, such answers aren't likely to give you the correct path for *you* to take on your way to becoming a better programmer.  You need to decide how to learn, and then do it.

Sorry that your question isn't getting good support on these sites, but the reason is because these sites aren't meant to support that sort of question.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

I took a look at your accounts to try to find links to the specific question, and I notice you have very vague and general question titles, especially on SO. A good title is vital to getting the attention of the best answerers. "Should I be using scripting in this circumstance?" , "Algorithm and script definition", and "Error on customers computer" are likely only to get attention from editors and closers.

My other piece of advice is to say what you've tried. If you ask "how do I get to Carnegie Hall?" and I say "practice, practice, practice", and you feel you're practising already, my answer is frustrating. But if you said in the question what you've tried, and what happened when you tried, then you're more likely to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for editing the question with phenomenal MS Paint skills, but also consider starting a bounty.

sometimes a question is too obscure or difficult for an average user, and from what I understand, the bounty system was designed for this. 
[image]