# Merging questions

Tags: support, questions

My question was closed as a duplicate of another question I also asked, this explains it for those that care.

[How many times can I ask the same question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94484/159879)

How can I merge these questions so they are one question ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flag one for moderator attention.  Ask for the questions to be merged, and provide link(s) to the other question(s).  A mod will determine if its worthwhile/meaningful to do so.