# What to do if you create a duplicate of your OWN question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This sounds pretty stupid, but I can see I asked the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378702/how-to-write-the-charmatcher-equivalent-for-the-regex-word-character) question [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283730/shortcuts-for-guavas-charmatcher-creation). (*)

I guess I should delete it, but isn't it impolite to the people who bothered answering? Or should I only close it?

---

(*) This shows that I need it again. And that I should read the answers. And get more sleep.

Comment: Your first link leads to a user.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby: Yeah, I was scanning through the real profile already..

Comment: I think the answer is a simple "do what you do when you find a duplicate, vote to close".

Comment: flag one of your post as duplicate of the other one which has more genuine answer

Comment: Sadly I've done this too (asked my own question twice)

Comment: @scunliffe: Wait until you research a problem, find a question with a useful answer on SO, want to upvote it and learn that you can't upvote your own posts.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby yeah I've done that too... or at least searched for an answer.. found one, and only after reading the whole thing think... "This guy is a genius!" then spot the Avatar and realize it is yourself. ;-) Just more proof of the power of SO.

Comment: @scunliffe: First I thought, I was just stupid. Then I hoped, I was at least unique. Finally, you robbed me of my illusions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the basic, perhaps fundamental, **suggestions** to *new* users is: SEARCH FIRST! The same applies to regular users... here are some guidelines/references:

- [How to ask a smart question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18584/168244)
- [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/168244)

---

Duplication is fine if it turns out that the problem can be approached from different angles. Moreover, the duplicate question may be the landing place for others searching for similar solutions - a good thing. From there they can follow the duplicate links until their question is solved, or they realize they're actually looking for something else.

Since you are the keeper of both questions here, there are the following considerations:

1. If the duplicate (newer) question is different in any way and may benefit the *community* from remaining where it is, then keep it.
2. If the duplicate (newer) question is no different yet have answers that may contribute to the *community*, [flag it for moderator attention and request a merge with the duplicate source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94636/168244).
3. None of the above? The choice is yours to remove it or keep it.

I've emphasized the word *community* in the above options, since they ultimately benefit from the knowledge-base in questions/answers over time.